# pentaho modify and print a parameter while exporting to excel

Tags: excel, report, pentaho, designer

I use pentaho report designer. I have got businessdate parameter in my prpt file. This has the value of the date range which is used to filter the sql query. I am able to handle and modify it while exporting to html however I have a problem in exporting to excel.

The date range comes in the formats below:

```
 - BETWEEN {d '2014-01-01'} AND {d '2014-01-31'}
 - IN ({d '2014-01-14'},{d '2014-01-15'}, {d '2014-01-19'} ,{d '2014-01-20'},{d '2014-01-21'})
```

I like to find out max and min date and display it. However in this case with excel, I am happy with displaying them separated with commas like shown below.

```
- 2014-01-01, 2014-01-31
- 2014-01-14, 2014-01-15, 2014-01-19, 2014-01-20, 2014-01-21
```

If I use the basic formula show below, it works in  in excel but it does not work when I apply it to excel - formula section of the businessDate element in pentaho report designer.

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B4,"{d '",""), "BETWEEN", ""), "IN", ""),"'}",", "), " AND ", ""),")",""),"(",))
```

It does not have to be this way. I am happy with any method suggested to format this raw date range before printing to excel.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting a lot of time, I have found a way which works for all export types. As I said in my question, I was modifying date for html print by using "Structure Tab" --> Select "Master Report" --> "Attributes" Tab --> html -> "append-header" attribute.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function init() {

    var tableList = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
     var businessDate = document.getElementById("businessDatePeriodSelected");
     businessDate.innerHTML = businessDate.innerHTML+"testDateModified";
    }

    window.onload = init;

    </script>
```

This piece of code does the job. However just for html. I needed to come up with something new. I was looking for a solution for excel and pdf exports as well.

HERE IS THE SOLUTION:
Click on "Data" tab next to the "Structure" tab on the right top side. You will see "Functions" in the tree. Right click and hit "Add functions". Select "Script" -->"Bean-Scripting Framework (BSF)". Select function created under Functions. Give it a name and add the code below to the "Expression" section. [This does not need a starting or ending tag]

```
/* businessdate is one of my parameters that I like to display on the report.
dataRow is automatically recognized by the interpreter which can be used for calling parameter values. It seems like came out of nowhere.*/


         String value = dataRow.get("businessdate"); 

            value= value.replaceAll("[^0-9\\-\\{\\}]", ""); 
            value= value.replaceAll("[\\{]", ""); // replace all {
            value= value.replaceAll("[\\}]", ","); // replace all }

            value= value.substring(0, value.length()-1);
            String[] dateArr = value.split(",");

            return dateArr[0] +" - "+dateArr[dateArr.length-1];
```

The last thing you need to do is drag and drop your function somewhere suitable on your report. It will locate a textbox which will display the modified businessdate.

If you like to print a parameter on your pentaho report, this does the job for all exports  (html, pdf and excel). You can also modify it before printing. This [link](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshmanual.html) pretty helpful as the syntax is slightly different at some points.

good luck.